# How do I make a dialogue box similar to this in CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a dialogue box that looks similar to this in css3 (minus text boxes and buttons, and forgot password link):
[image]

I think I can do something like:

```
<div id="mydialoguebox">
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<div id="text">
Please review your account before continuing.
<div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is there always seems to be a gap in between the top of the div and the h1 tag. I am also unsure how to add the "close" image with the x. Is it better to shove the authorization required and the image into its own div? Im looking for the best way to do this without JQuery UI or any javascript.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery-UI's dialog. It makes this dialog almost to a T (excluding the images and color scheme).

Comment: I do not want to use JQuery-UI.

Comment: I'm not advising you do so, however the CSS library jQuery includes has UI elements (Dialog, Widget, etc.) that almost perfectly match the example you've provided. It's open source and easy to view what styles they use--just modify them for your purpose.

Comment: I understand, but I would prefer to do this without relying on any external libraries or existing styles to help me know CSS3 better, but I am stuck on making just a simple dialogue box.

Comment: You're missing my point; I'm saying *look at* jquery UI and how the library itself does it, then modify the styles to fit your purpose, then use *only those styles* (not the entire jQuery-UI CSS) in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/t6f5v/

Here's my basic idea of how you could build this. It need some further improvement, but for the moment, you could start with it.

CSS:

```
<style>

    div.box {
        width:          400px;
        height:         200px;
        margin:         20px;
        border:         1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius:  6px;
    }

    div.box > header {
        height:         30px;
        padding:        10px;
        background:     #777;
        color:          #333;
    }
    div.box > header > h1 {
        float:          left;
        font-size:      14px;
        font-weight:    normal;
    }
    div.box > header > a {
        display:        inline-block;
        float:          right;
        width:          11px;
        height:         11px;
        margin-top:     10px;
        background:     url(http://www.geocaching.com/images/stockholm/mini/close.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    }

    div.box > section {
        padding:        10px;
    }
    div.box > section form, div.box > section fieldset {
        margin:         0;
        padding:        0;
        border:         0;
    }

</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <header>
        <h1>Authorisation Required</h1>
        <a href=""></a>
    </header>
    <section>
        <p>Please verify your …
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <input type="text">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some divs - position them 1 after the other. Have one one colour, the other another. Then you could use some fancy css border-radius styles.

http://border-radius.com/